# Change Y axis unit in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am new to matlab.
I  have plotted a graph in matlab like below,

[image]

here the y axis units incremented by 0.1 ie., `(0,0.1,0.2,0.3,..)` .

Is it possible to change the y axis units like `0,0.01,0.02,0.03,..`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, after your plot command try:

```
 range=0:0.01:0.6; % or whatever range you want
 set(gca,'YTicK',range,'YTickLabels',range)
```

Just beware that this will probably wont look nice...

In case what you wanted is to change **just** the labels from 0.1 to 0.01 etc but keep the tick positions, jsut use

```
set(gca,'YTickLabels',range)
```

Comment: thanks for reply .. it made changes in label. but there is no changes in line.

Comment: why wont you rephrase the question in  a way that explains what you want?

Comment: Also, if you just want to change the scale, you can also use the `yticks` command together with the `set` command above: `set(gca,'YTickLabels', 0.1*yticks)`